# how to make cropped UIView to show the bottom of that UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I need to make something like this

[image]

as you can see, there are two half round views in the right and left side that will show the bottom UIView( UIView with dark blue background color).how to achieve this?

I simplify the problem to be like the picture below:

[image]

what should I do to that `white view` to make cropped effect and actually show the background view (blue view) ?

edit: no, I can't give blue color to that white view. as you can see in the first picture, the background color is actually gradient color, thats why i need to "crop" this UIView to show the background color of the bottom UIView

Comment: Well the most obvious answer is - give it the same background color as that of the view background view?

Comment: no, at this case it can't be like that. because the background color is gradient color

Comment: I did the same view few months ago. If you need it yet, I will share with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the view that you want to achieve. The goal is that you need to draw this view with corners and arcs. If you need any help or explanation about how I did that you can just ask.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(croppedView)

    croppedView.cutViewCornersWith(cornerRadius: 20, arcRadius: 14)
}

lazy var croppedView: CroppedView = {
    let cv = CroppedView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: 0,
                                       width: self.view.frame.width - 120,
                                       height: 400))
    cv.center = view.center
    cv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return cv
}()

}

import UIKit

class CroppedView: UIView {

func cutViewCornersWith(cornerRadius: CGFloat, arcRadius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let width = self.frame.width
    let height = self.frame.height
    let arcCenter = height - height/3

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius),
                radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(270.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: 0.0))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius),
                radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(90.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: arcCenter - arcRadius))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width, y: arcCenter),
                radius: arcRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(270.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(90.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: false)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - cornerRadius))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius),
                radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(90.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius),
                radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(90.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: arcCenter + arcRadius))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: arcCenter),
                radius: arcRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(90.0).toRadians(),
                endAngle: CGFloat(270.0).toRadians(),
                clockwise: false)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: arcCenter - arcRadius))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    path.close()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}

}

extension CGFloat {
    func toRadians() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180.0
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in code.  You need to set a 'mask'.  I am not sure if you can do this using the InterfaceBuilder (I stay well clear of it).  Here is the gist of the code that I used (cut from my code, but untested).  Here I make a transparent strip the width of the view and holeHeight tall - I was custom drawing the middle of a picker.

```
class HoledView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor?.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.frame.height - holeHeight) / 2, width: self.frame.width, height: holeHeight)
        path.addRect(rect)
        path.addRect(self.bounds)
        layer.path = path
        layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        self.layer.mask = layer
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that the mask defines the area that the view will draw into.  In my example there is a hole in the middle of the mask, so the view will not draw into that area, and it stays completely transparent.

Although I did this using layers, [it may be doable using a mask view instead](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask):

> The view’s alpha channel determines how much of the view’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block that content.